# "wegnehmen" Conjugation

Tags: verb, conjugation

I was watching the movie X-Men first class and I was watching the scene where Fassbender's character was in Argentina. Here is the script that I was able to extract from youtube slow play and searching online:

> *Magneto*: Deutsches Bier
>       *Bar guy:* Klaro
>       *Pig farmer:* Ja ist Bitburger, schmeckt gut ne? Hahahaha
>       *Magneto:* Das Beste. Was hat Sie nach Argentinien verschlagen?
>       *Pig farmer:* Och... das Klima. Ich bin Schweinebauer. Hahahaha
>       *Tailor:* Ich bin Schneider... schon seit meiner Kindheit. Mein Vater hat die schönsten Anzüge Düsseldorfs gemacht.
>       *Magneto:* Meine Eltern kamen aus Düsseldorf.
>       *Tailor:* Wie ist der Name?
>       *Magneto:* Sie hatten keinen Namen. **Ihr Name wurde ihnen weggenommen.** Schweinebauern und Schneider. Blut und Ehre, ja, was würden Sie gerne zuerst verlieren?
>       *Pig farmer:* Wir hatten unsere Befehle.
>       *Magneto:* Also Blut...

I am able to identify the help verb and sentence structure of all the lines except for this one: *Ihr Name wurde ihnen weggenommen*. To me the subject is *Ihr name* and I can't seem to find any resources where the verb *wegnehmen* uses a *wurde* without *haben* as the helper verb. Can someone explain why its not *Ihr Name hat ihnen weggenommen*?

Comment: See [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:wegnehmen) for full conjugation table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's passive voice, past tense.

> Ihr Name wurde ihnen weggenommen.

*Their name was taken away from them.*

However, it's a rough translation into German. German speakers (as Magneto is, obviously) would simply say

> Ihr Name wurde ihnen genommen.

as this is the usual expression for items of honor, as the own name, memories, and such.

(The background is the number tattoos of the KZ inmates. They were punished for using their names instead of these numbers.)

Comment: So is wegnehmen used more for physical objects and nehmen more for abstract objects such as name and memories?

Comment: Both *wegnehmen* and *nehmen* may be used for physical objects. *Wegnehmen* means *by force* then. *Nimm doch bitte noch ein Stück Kuchen*. It's an exaggeration to apply this to your name, your memories, even to your breath. For these cases, *nehmen* already connotates violence. *Das Feuer nimmt mir den Atem.*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `Ihr Name wurde ihnen weggenommen` translates to the English `Their name was taken from them`. `Ihr Name` refers to the name of the parents he is talking about.

The reason for conjugating with `wurde` instead of `haben` is because this sentence stands in passive form, just like in the English translation.